# How to change the width of the google+ comments widget

Tags: html, css, google-plus

I am attempting to adjust the width of the Google+ comment widget for the mobile device. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tabs-3"><img src="/images/icon-facebook.png" alt="Facebook Icon" /><p class="tabTitle">Comment on <strong class="fbBlue">Facebook</strong></p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tabs-4"><img src="/images/icon-plus.png" alt="Google+ Icon" /><p class="tabTitle">Comment on <strong class="googleRed">Google+</strong></p></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=654528351241254";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.harvekeronline.com/3dlm-lesson-your-ideal-life/" data-colorscheme="light" data-numposts="10" data-width="100%" data-order-by="reverse_time" data-mobile="200px"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
    </script>
    **<div class="g-comments"
        data-href="http://www.harvekeronline.com/3dlm-lesson-your-ideal-life/"
        data-width="medium"
        data-first_party_property="BLOGGER"
        data-view_type="FILTERED_POSTMOD">
     </div>**
     </div>
 </div>
```

It is possible that the "tabs" div is messing this up, but other then that, I have no idea.
Does anyone have any suggestions?